# CodeIgniter | Certain controllers won't load depending on .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two controllers inside my CodeIgniter project. 
- home.php
- dashboard.php

For some reason, my htaccess makes dashboard.php unavailable when I change it to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ci_intro/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] # THIS LINE HERE
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

However, when I change it to the code below, home.php is unavailable.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ci_intro/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] # THIS LINE HERE
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I don't understand why, anyone have an idea of why it would do this?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: could you show your controller and a screenshot of your file structure?

Comment: Try, Rename home.php to Home.php

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteBase /ci_intro
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
     #Send request via index.php
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    </IfModule>
```

And make controller home.php as **class Home extends CI_Controller** and Rename it as **Home.php** Same for dashboard.php